# Logic flow for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

So essentially the problem is that the findLowest function isn't doing what I had planned for it to do. I know it's a logic error but I can't seem to find out why the variables aren't updating. They always default to the values they are instantiated with.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void findLowest(int regAccidents[], int arraySize, string regNames[]);
int getNumAccidents(string);
const int NUM_REGIONS = 5;

int main(){
    string regionNames[NUM_REGIONS] = { "North", "South", "East", "West", "Central" };
    int regionAccidents[NUM_REGIONS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_REGIONS; i++){//Populates the accident array
        regionAccidents[i] = getNumAccidents(regionNames[i]);

        if (regionAccidents[i] < 0)//checks to see if there are any accidents counts lower than 0
            regionAccidents[i] = 0;
        }

        findLowest(regionAccidents, NUM_REGIONS, regionNames);
}

int getNumAccidents(string region){//returns the accidents for a specific region to be assigned to the regionAccidents[] array in main()

    int regionAccidents = 0;
    cout << "How many accidents for " << region << "? ";
    cin >> regionAccidents;
    return regionAccidents;

}

void findLowest(int regAccidents[], int arraySize, string regNames[]){  //used to determine what the lowest number of accidents is
    int lowest = regAccidents[0];                                       //once that is found, update the lowRegion string of the accident location
    string lowRegion = regNames[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        if (regAccidents[i] < regAccidents[i++]){
            lowest = regAccidents[i];
            lowRegion = regNames[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "The region with the lowest amount of accidents is: " << lowRegion << endl;
    cout << "The lowest number of accidents is: " << lowest << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is this the smallest possible piece of code that demonstrates your problem? If not, what is?

Comment: It is only the findLowest function at the bottom. The whole code I provided because if people needed it I wouldn't have to change anything about the original program.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What input did you use? Given those input, what was the outcome? Any exception? What compiler and platform you are using? You missed out a lot of information

Comment: The question has since been answered by several people below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (regAccidents[i] < regAccidents[i++]) { ...
```

is dead wrong, you need to compare the current index to the lowest found so far:

```
if (regAccidents[i] < lowest) { ...
```

The expression `regAccidents[i] < regAccidents[i++]` will *never* be true because you're comparing the same items in the array. It *will,* however, increment `i` when you least expect it. Not that that actually matters here since it's a secondary problem totally hidden by your primary one :-)

Comment: You are completely correct. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have logic errors in your code. The findLowest should look like the following:

```
int lowest = regAccidents[0];       
string lowRegion = regNames[0];
for (int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++){
        //^^you have initialized lowest as regAccidents[0], so search from 1
    if (regAccidents[i] < lowest ){
        //^^if current is smaller than lowest, update lowest and name    
        lowest = regAccidents[i];
        lowRegion = regNames[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are completely correct. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You did say anything about what your getting as an output now.
are you overrunning the array with this line's increment?

if (regAccidents[i] < regAccidents[i++])

Comment: You did say anything about what your getting as an output now.
are you overrunning the array with this line's increment?

if (regAccidents[i] < regAccidents[i++])


The question has since been answered. However, the times when it would go over is when the statement was changed to:

if (regAccidents[i] <= regAccidents[i++])

This would look to the lowest value of int possible and since it is the lowest value it overrides every other value tested. It would also negate the lowRegion string to null.